# ScrollEndNotification is triggered recursively when I change the sign - flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

`The below code does run recursively, when the sign is changed in scrollEndNotification(as I commented). But if I change the sign to + the code runs without recursion. I could not understand why?

The conditions are same in both cases.

This is from bard explanations

The scrollController.jumpTo() method is called.
The if statement in the onNotification() callback is evaluated. The condition is always true, so the if statement is executed.
The scrollController.jumpTo() method is called again.
The if statement in the onNotification() callback is evaluated again. The condition is still true, so the if statement is executed.
This process repeats indefinitely, resulting in a recursive loop.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    String message = 'New';
    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
    int _index = 1;
    bool isScrolled = false;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      // scroll to the second item when the app starts
      scrollController.jumpTo(300);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      scrollController.addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          isScrolled = true;
        });
      });

      return Scaffold(
        // creating appbar
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('GeeksforGeeks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),

        // Creating a container and giving it some styling properties
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  message,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // using NotificationListener Widget
            Expanded(
                child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                // Logic of scrollNotification
                if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                  setState(() {
                    message = 'Scroll Start';
                  });
                } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                  setState(() {
                    message = 'Scroll Updated';
                  });
                } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                  setState(() {
                    message = 'Scroll End';
                  });

                  if (scrollController.position.pixels / 300 <= 1) {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                      print(800 + (484 / 2));
                      scrollController.jumpTo(800 + (484 / 2));
                    });
                  } else if (scrollController.position.pixels / 300 > 0) {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                      scrollController.jumpTo(
                          ((scrollController.position.pixels / 300).round() - 1) *
                                  300 +
                              (484 / 2));
                    });
                  }
                }
                return false;
              },
              // child of type required. Which means its compulsory to pass in NotificationListener
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  //  print(constraints.maxHeight);
                  return ListView.builder(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              height: index == 0 ? 800 : 300,
                              // color: Colors.red,
                              child: Center(child: Text('Item: $index'))),
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
            ))
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

`